# Can not append elements to div

Tags: javascript, html, append

My Javascript is intended to do the following.

I have a parent div with 6 children nodes. I create 3 divs with JS and then append them into the parent. I then insert the original 6 children nodes into the 3 divs I just created and appended to the original parent. These 3 divs were siblings of the original 6 elements and are now parents of them.

This almost works. But two of the original children are not appended to the middle div as I have intended in the Javascript. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Below is the Javascript and here is the link to the web page the script is being executed on.

http://digitalenamel.com/espresso-event-schedule/

```
setTimeout( function() {
    try{
        var calendar = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendarChildren = calendar.children;
        console.log("How many children does #calendar have? " + calendarChildren.length);
        var calendarHeaders = document.getElementsByClassName('fc-header');  
        var calendarBodies = document.getElementsByClassName('fc-content');
        var containerForCalendars1 = document.createElement("div");
        var containerForCalendars2 = document.createElement("div");
        var containerForCalendars3 = document.createElement("div");
        calendar.appendChild(containerForCalendars1);
        calendar.appendChild(containerForCalendars2);
        calendar.appendChild(containerForCalendars3);
        containerForCalendars1.appendChild(calendarHeaders[0]); 
        containerForCalendars1.appendChild(calendarBodies[0]);
        containerForCalendars2.appendChild(calendarHeaders[1]);
        containerForCalendars2.appendChild(calendarBodies[1]);
        containerForCalendars3.appendChild(calendarHeaders[2]);
        containerForCalendars3.appendChild(calendarBodies[2]);
        console.log("How many elements with the class of fc-header are inside the calendarHeaders array? " + calendarHeaders.length);
        console.log("How many elements with the class of fc-content are inside the calendarBodies array? " + calendarHeaders.length);
    }catch(err){
        console.log("There was a general error with JS for calendar.");
    }
}, 8000);
```

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/xe1ssxeu/ reproduced error

Comment: You should try to duplicate the problem over as JSFiddle if you can, this would make it significantly easier for someone to debug without access to your dev environment. Also, a lazy programmer would be creating reusable functions and possibly jQuery for something like this. The way you have done this is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you. I'll try that. I appreciate your response. You're right. I'm not lazy. Just very unskilled. Ha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your updated question, I've made an attempt. I've eschewed your method as I said, it's a bit over-the-top. You had jQuery enabled in the JSFiddle so I used it.

As you mentioned you're learning I've included some comments that should explain what is going on.

```
// Set this jQuery to run once the page is ready.
$('document').ready(function() {
    // Create a list of all the headers & all the contents
    var headers = $('.fc-header');
    var contents = $('.fc-content');

    // Cycle through the headers & contents (assuming they're equal in length)
    for(i=0; i<headers.length; i++) {

        // Add a div to calendar with an id of the for iterator so we can 
        // access it.
        $('#calendar').append('<div id="' + i + '"></div>');

        // Access that div using the id we added, then append the i'th header
        // and the i'th content.
        $('#' + i).append(headers[i]);
        $('#' + i).append(contents[i]);

        // Remove the id as we don't need it later.
        $('#' + i).removeAttr('id');
    }
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xe1ssxeu/1/)